# Table-valued Function vs View vs Multi-Statement Table Valued Function

Tags: sql

1. В чём разница выбора информации из
       множества столбцов, не считая тот
       факт, что в `Multi-Statement Table
       Valued Function` можно писать
       какую-то логику.   Допустим, если
       нужно вытащить просто данные из
       нескольких таблиц?   Когда стоит
       использовать:

   1) `Table-valued Function`?
    2) `Multi-Statement Table Valued Function`?  
    3) View`?
2. Допустим, что `Multi-Statement Table
       Valued Function` используется тогда,
       когда нужна какая-то логика.   Тогда
       вопрос в

   1) `Table-valued Function`?
    2) `View`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется я разобрался 
Table-valued Function vs View vs Multi-Statement Table Valued Function